# Force stop java script executing function

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo

I have a dojo tree view and when i click on a node, a java script refreshes a grid. 
I need to stop any running java scripts after node being clicked and before refreshing data.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is (for the most part) single threaded so when you get your click event, that code is the only thing running. Your code could be interrupted by some events, is that what your concern is? If so, you could unhook these events before refreshing and then hook them back up afterwards if you really needed to.  Hard to say what the best approach would be without seeing some code.

Comment: for example when some java scripts are running, when you press Esc or click stop on browser, all java scripts stop exciting. I needed something like this. Anyway, I solved my problem by window.stop() at the top of my onNodeClick function.